# What happens to someone that was "banned" if their answers got migrated to the new site?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

Suppose someone posted a bunch of bad (downvoted) answers that got them banned on the old MSE site. And suppose the related questions were migrated to the new MSO site.

What would happen? Would the answer ban follow this person to MSO? Would the answer ban on MSE be lifted if the removal of those questions brought the person's (negative) score below the critical level?

Answer (score 6):

Child metas don't have answer bans. And migrated content is soft-deleted on the source site (same way as any other deleted post), not fully removed as if it never existed.

So, basically, nothing special would happen.

Comment: Interesting.  Does the migration based delete actually make things worse on the sourse site then? Or is this an exception to the "deletions make it worse"

Comment: @RichardTingle Migration has no impact on this whatsoever. It doesn't make things worse and it doesn't make things better *than a regular deletion*.

Comment: So if I ask a question on the History site, and it is migrated to e.g. the Politics site, and thereby gets deleted from History, it hurts my History site score? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @TomAu Question bans have different criteria from answer bans. Questions also aren't immediately deleted upon migration. *And* questions bans aren't even enabled on the vast majority of sites in the network. In short, don't worry about it. Migrations aren't causing unsuspecting folks to get banned when they wouldn't be otherwise.

Comment: @TomAu But to actually answer your question... yes. *If* question bans are enabled on the site *and* the migration stub is deleted, that question would contribute to the question ban check the same way that a *normally deleted* question would.

Comment: @AnnaLear, Why does this meta have question bans but child metas don't? Shouldn't the rationale for them (either have ban or have no ban) be the same?

Comment: @Pacerier This site is called "meta" but it's actually a main Q&A site the topic of which is "the Stack Exchange network". It is not a meta in the same sense as child metas are and it doesn't play by the same rules.

Comment: @AnnaLear, Yes I understand the sites are coded differently, but why would the decision to ban-or-not  be different?

Comment: @Pacerier It's not a matter of coding, it's a matter of how the site is used. Meta SE is a Q&A site in and of itself, not a site for discussing a Q&A site and its operation. A child meta has a parent site that... I guess, matters more? Most disciplinary things we have (like suspensions) are issued on the main site and also apply to meta. MSE has no parent. It *is* the parent.

Comment: @AnnaLear, If the user is banned from posting on the parent site, he is still allowed to post on the childmeta (since there are no question bans there). So rephrasing what I meant: Why is the reason for lifting bans in childmeta not applicable to MSE? What's the reason for lifting bans in childmeta?

Comment: @Pacerier If a user is blocked on the main site, they can come to their child meta to get help with understanding why that happened and how to recover. In general, question or answer bans earned on one site don't extend to other sites. Why would they extend to meta here? Once again, it's a completely separate site despite having "meta" in its name. Also, metas are for bug reports and the like. Blocking someone here on MSE because they don't know how to ask a good question over on, I don't know, Ask Ubuntu makes very little sense.

Comment: @AnnaLear, True, we can see that banning on meta sites make very little sense, even if it doesn't have a parent site. So why does MSE still retain the ban system?

Comment: @Pacerier If someone keeps consistently posting bad suggestions or bad answers, we don't want to allow them to do that indefinitely. It's a lot harder to get banned from asking or answering on MSE.